# Why is user input in Ruby different from a given string already inside the code?

Tags: ruby, string, comparison, user-input

My Ruby program evaluates strings in a function called `func1`.  It asks for user input when it runs.  The string comparison `if` statement
does not work on user input no matter what.  I can interactively enter the string that should be the same as the program-defined variable constant. But the function interprets the two strings differently. I have added extra debugging steps to verify the string is correct. But I still fail to see why the `func1` sees user input different from the way I, a human, sees the input.  I expect func1 to receive the user-inputted string `foobar` and recognize it. This is not what is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Ruby program:

```
def func1(x)
    if x == 'foobar' then
      print "you gave this function foobar"
      puts " "
    else
      print "you did NOT give this function foobar"
    end
end

def prompt(*args)
    print("Enter a string: ")
    coolstring = gets
    return coolstring
end

func1("foobar")
y = prompt
print(y)
func1(y)
```

Here is some output that shows I entered the string "foobar":

> you gave this function foobar
>
> Enter a string: foobar
>
> foobar
>
> you did NOT give this function foobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `gets` the newline that ends the input is stored in the variable:

```
pry(main)> gets
qwe
# => "qwe\n"
```

To remove it, use [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-chomp). It removes a separator (by default a newline) from the end of the string:

```
pry(main)> a = gets
asd
#=> "asd\n"
pry(main)> a.chomp
#=> "asd"
```

And in your case:

```
def prompt(*args)
    print("Enter a string: ")
    coolstring = gets.chomp # <<<<<<<<<<<< here
    return coolstring
end
```